# Splitting up pages in a Seam application

Tags: jboss, split, seam

I'm quite new to Seam and am working on a relatively large project at work. The application is quite complicated in that there's a lot going on a single page at any time. I'm trying to figure out how to structure this and would like some feedback.

A good example to base this on would be Facebook (or a similar social media app). Facebook has a ton of stuff going on the screen. If all that logic were in a single view and backing bean, the files would be monolithic in size.

The way I see it is you'd have different components. For example, in Facebook, there'd be a component that handles showing your friends or friends in common with another person, there'd be another component handling invitations, suggestions, etc, etc.

All this is separate functionality being displayed on a single page however, in some cases, although being separate components, they're related at the end of the end. For example, if I click something in the main screen (i.e. not the elements in the sidebars) that generates an ajax request, a component in the sidebar might need to be updated automatically or rerendered.

Further than just sidebar components, there might be multiple disparate elements in the main area of a page (for example, a tabbed area where each panel could, in actuality be a separate or a separate view of the page).

It would be ugly if I had to handle everything in a single backing bean or something similar. It makes sense to me that each of these disparate elements have their own controllers (backing beans?) and what not. If I do an action in component x, it's bean could fire an event that could be listened to from component y's bean (thus causing component y to be rerendered).

Any ideas or resources I could look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seam certainly allows division of pages into multiple fragments with separate backing components.  They can be quite independent but can also interact.

To learn it, start with [the Seam tutorial at JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html) and the book [Seam in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988401).

For the Ajax interaction you're looking for, you might also want to look at the [RichFaces Developer Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/).